# Where can I manage TLS settings on GCloud?

Tags: sql-server, ssl, jdbc, tls1.2

I have a server (A) hosted on GCloud VM instance which points to an SQL database (B) also hosted on GCloud. Within the program on server A there is a JDBC connector used to access and edit info on server B. Recently after restarting server A, the connector records the following error:

`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12]".`

The SQL instance (B) is set to 'allow unsecure connections'.

If anyone could help me solve this error message I will appreciate it greatly.
I am very new to all of these things, so it would be great if you could be very descriptive with any responses.

Comment: The SQL Server instance might be configured to accept insecure connections (i.e.: in SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols > Properties > Certificate > ForceEncryption=false) but it sounds like your JDBC connection is configured to require encryption. And the version of JRE you just upgraded to has disabled TLS 1.0 and 1.1 by default.

Comment: I'd be seriously concerned about the patch level of the host operating system and/or SQL Server itself if it's still wanting to connect using TLS 1.0. TLS 1.2 support has been available to SQL Server editions going [all the way back to 2008 SP3](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3135244-tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server-e4472ef8-90a9-13c1-e4d8-44aad198cdbe).